# 'Login failed for user' error when using SQL Server, but not when using tedious

Tags: sql-server, npm, database-connection

I'm trying to connect to a SQL Server Express database setup on a Windows 10 machine in network from a macbook running the following code. I can connect using `tedious`, but not using `mssql`. It's as if the username or password is wrong. The reason I want to get `mssql` working is for the pooling and because it appears to have more support... otherwise I would just use `tedious`. The code is creating both connections and the output shows tedious connecting but `mssql` fails.

```
const express = require('express');
const sql = require('mssql');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();

var Connection = require('tedious').Connection;

// Body Parser Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// CORS Middleware
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});

// define listineng port
const PORT = 5006;

// define tedious config
var config = {
            server: "JAMBER-VR1.local",
            userName: "testuser",
            password: "testuserpass",
            database: "SQLEXPRESS",
            options: {
              encrypt: false
            }
     };

var connection = new Connection (config);

connection.on('connect', function(err){

    if(err!=null){
      console.log(err);
         console.log("not connected - tedious");
    }
    else{
          console.log("Connected - tedious")
          connection.close();
    };
});


// Define SQL config

const dbConfig = {
  user: 'testuser',
  password: 'testuserpass',
  server: 'JAMBER-VR1.local',
  database: 'SQLEXPRESS',
  // port: 1433,
  // logging: true,
  options: {encrypt: false},
  pool: {
    max: 100,
    min: 0,
    idleTimeoutMillis: 30000
  }
}

const executeQuery = async () => {
  try {
    let pool = await sql.connect(dbConfig);
    console.log("pool connected - mssql");
    let result = await pool.request()
      .input('input_parameter', sql.Int, value)
      .query('select * from donor')

    console.log("Result: ", result);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("Error: ", err);
  }
}

executeQuery();
```

I'm getting the following error.

> [nodemon] starting `node index.js`
> Running on port 5006
> Connected - tedious
> Error:  { ConnectionError: Login failed for user 'testuser'.
>
> at Connection.tedious.once.err (/Users/jordanszymczyk/Code/TRTL/server_sql /node_modules/mssql/lib/tedious.js:237:17)
> at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:273:13)
> at Connection.emit (events.js:182:13)
> at Connection.processLogin7Response (/Users/jordanszymczyk/Code/TRTL/server_sql/node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js:1292:16)
> at Connection.message (/Users/jordanszymczyk/Code/TRTL/server_sql/node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js:1805:14)
> at Connection.dispatchEvent (/Users/jordanszymczyk/Code/TRTL/server_sql/node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js:1004:38)
> at MessageIO. (/Users/jordanszymczyk/Code/TRTL/server_sql/node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js:884:18)
> at MessageIO.emit (events.js:182:13)
> at ReadablePacketStream. (/Users/jordanszymczyk/Code/TRTL/server_sql/node_modules/tedious/lib/message-io.js:104:16)
> at ReadablePacketStream.emit (events.js:182:13)
> code: 'ELOGIN',
> originalError:
> { ConnectionError: Login failed for user 'testuser'.
> at ConnectionError (/Users/jordanszymczyk/Code/TRTL/server_sql/node_modules/tedious/lib/errors.js:12:12)
> at Parser. (/Users/jordanszymczyk/Code/TRTL/server_sql/node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js:628:33)
> at Parser.emit (events.js:182:13)
> at Parser. (/Users/jordanszymczyk/Code/TRTL/server_sql/node_modules/tedious/lib/token/token-stream-parser.js:54:15)
> at Parser.emit (events.js:182:13)
> at addChunk (/Users/jordanszymczyk/Code/TRTL/server_sql/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:291:12)
> at readableAddChunk (/Users/jordanszymczyk/Code/TRTL/server_sql/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:278:11)
> at Parser.Readable.push (/Users/jordanszymczyk/Code/TRTL/server_sql/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:245:10)
> at Parser.Transform.push (/Users/jordanszymczyk/Code/TRTL/server_sql/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_transform.js:148:32)
> at doneParsing (/Users/jordanszymczyk/Code/TRTL/server_sql/node_modules/tedious/lib/token/stream-parser.js:110:18)
> message: 'Login failed for user 'testuser'.',
> code: 'ELOGIN' },
> name: 'ConnectionError' }

You can see the console.log("Connected - tedious") prints, then the mssql error follows immediately.
I've also tried using the local IP with the same results.
Testing through sqlcmd works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SQLEXPRESS` will be the name of your SQL Server Express server instance (ie- Server).  I don't see it in your code, but I'm guessing the database name is not SQLEXPRESS?

In your mssql connection dbConfig try changing `Database` to the real name of the database you created on your SQL Express instance.

Comment: The tedious connection doesn't fail...it's the mssql connection I can't get to work.  But the dbConfig for mssql is practically the same.  What should my dbConfig look like if the connection like the following works from terminal...  sqlcmd -S JAMBER-VR1.local\\SQLEXPRESS,1433 -U testuser -P testuserpass

Comment: Regarding the database name...it's the default for that user, so I think that's why I don't need it when logging in with sqlcmd.  But the following command that includes the database works.   sqlcmd -S JAMBER-VR1.local\\SQLEXPRESS.donor.dbo.donor,1433 -U testuser -P testuserpass

Comment: Got it!  Had to remove SQLEXPRESS all together.  Set server to 'SERVERNAME.local' and database to 'dbname'.  It was simple, but my problem was trying to incorporate SQLEXPRESS into the connection somehow.

Answer (score 4):

dont forget to active both authentication

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The fixed dgconfig is as follows:

```
const dbConfig = {
  user: 'testuser',
  password: 'testuserpass',
  server: 'JAMBER-VR1.local',
  database: 'donor',
  options: {encrypt: false},
  pool: {
    max: 100,
    min: 0,
    idleTimeoutMillis: 30000
  }
}
```

Removed SQLEXPRESS and replaced it with the database name.